# MvvmCross bind Viewmodel property to view property

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Is it possible to change viewmodel property from view? I had have tried fluent binding, but viewmodel property always null

**View**

```
    public class UserProfileView : MvxActivity
{

    private string _currentToken;
    public string CurrentToken { get; set; }
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        var accounts = AccountStore.Create(this).FindAccountsForService("Soundcloud").ToList();
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<UserProfileView, UserProfileViewModel>();
        set.Bind(this).For(v => v.CurrentToken).To(vm => vm.UserToken).TwoWay();
        set.Apply();
        accounts.ForEach(account =>
        {
            CurrentToken = account.Properties["access_token"];
        });
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.UsrProfile);
    }
}
```

**ModelView**

```
    private string _userToken;
    public string UserToken
    {
        get { return _userToken;}
        set { _userToken = value; RaisePropertyChanged("UserToken"); Update();}
    }
```

Comment: I would go with the (Tibet?) binding from xml usually local:MvxBind="CurrentToken UserToken"

Comment: It's always tries to get UserToken, but I'm need to set it in ModelView

Comment: So the binding is right but the value is not in the viewModel whats the problem then?

Comment: It might be that the Binding will not work out because that the View is not set yet. Try calling SetContentView() before the binding set. Check the output windows for possible mvvmcross warnings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be inheriting from `MvxActivity<TViewModel>`

```cs
public class UserProfileView : MvxActivity<UserProfileViewModel>
```

and then simply set

```cs
ViewModel.CurrentToken = account.Properties["access_token"];
```

This answers your *"Is it possible to change viewmodel property from view?"*. But this doesn't use databinding. If you really want to use data binding, you have to write a custom Binding for it, what may be too much effort in this case.

Comment: I'll have a look at after my CS:GO session ^^